# How to reduce the execution time in Parallel.ForEach function?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, parallel.foreach

Code:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    infoMap,
    map =>
    {
        var workItem = map.WorkItem;
        var parentInViews = viewMaps;
        var workbenchItem = map.WorkbenchItem;
        string LinkType = string.Empty;

        WorkItemLinkCollection linkedWorkItems = workItem.WorkItemLinkHistory;
        if (linkedWorkItems != null && linkedWorkItems.Count > 0)
            LinkType = linkedWorkItems[0].LinkTypeEnd.LinkType.ReferenceName;
        else if (workItem != null)
            LinkType = workItem.Store.WorkItemLinkTypes.LinkTypeEnds["Parent"].LinkType.ReferenceName;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LinkType))
        {
            var viewMap = parentInViews.FirstOrDefault();
            if (viewMap != null)
            {
                var linkName =  LinkType;
                var childType = viewMap.ChildType;

                ILinkItem itm = Factory.BuildLinkItem(linkName, workbenchItem, workbenchItem);
                lock (Addparents)
                {
                    Addparents.Add(itm);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

`Factory.BuildLinkItem` definition:

```
public static ILinkItem BuildLinkItem(string linkName, IWorkbenchItem parent, IWorkbenchItem child)
{         
       return new LinkItem { LinkName = linkName ?? string.Empty, Child = child, Parent = parent };
}
```

Totally `658 items` are present and it takes nearly **10 seconds** to execute the above `Parallel.ForEach` function.

Is it possible to reduce the execution time and if so, please suggest me a solution. Thanks.

**Note**: Apart from `Parallel.ForEach`, if any **alternate method** is there to increase the performance and reduce the execution time also, Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code and seeing where the time is spent?

Comment: Since, I don't have access to install, I haven't profile the code.

Comment: Why are you doing `Addparents.Add(itm)`? Why not do a parallel select with a `.ToList()` to put the items in a list?

Comment: @Enigmativity I guess because writing this kind of code is much more straightforward than combination of multiple Select() and Where() with all that state.

Comment: @Enigmativity, how to change the `Addparents.Add(itm);` to `parallel select with a .ToList()`. Thanks.

Comment: Euphoric seems to have done a good job doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the `lock` statement. The `mutex` mechanism behind it is extremely performance expensive compared to other synchronization mechanisms. I'm gonna bet 99.99% of those 10 seconds, the code spends locking and waiting in that critical section. Even non-parallel select would be much faster.

Your have two options. First is to use `.AsParallel()` `.Select()` and `.Where()` instead of `Parallel.ForEach` and adding into a collection inside a lock. I would highly recommend this. This way, the synchronization between operation on different items is handled automatically.

Second option is to use some kind of [concurrent collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that exist in .NET 4 instead of locking and normal collection. Those collections are specially optimized to extra quick adding of items, that is threadsafe.

This is little hack, how could you simply convert it to `AsParallel`:

```
infoMap.AsParallel().Select(
map =>
{
    var workItem = map.WorkItem;
    var parentInViews = viewMaps;
    var workbenchItem = map.WorkbenchItem;
    string LinkType = string.Empty;

    WorkItemLinkCollection linkedWorkItems = workItem.WorkItemLinkHistory;
    if (linkedWorkItems != null && linkedWorkItems.Count > 0)
        LinkType = linkedWorkItems[0].LinkTypeEnd.LinkType.ReferenceName;
    else if (workItem != null)
        LinkType = workItem.Store.WorkItemLinkTypes.LinkTypeEnds["Parent"].LinkType.ReferenceName;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LinkType))
    {
        var viewMap = parentInViews.FirstOrDefault();
        if (viewMap != null)
        {
            var linkName =  LinkType;
            var childType = viewMap.ChildType;

            ILinkItem itm = Factory.BuildLinkItem(linkName, workbenchItem, workbenchItem);

            return new {item = itm, filter=true};
        }
    }
    return new {item = (ILinkItem)null, filter=false};
})
.Where(x=>x.filter)
.Select(x=>x.item)
.ToList();
```

Comment: Can you update my code and change it accordingly your first option `First is to use .AsParallel() .Select() and .Where()`. Thanks.

Comment: @Euphoric - How can you be not sure that it is working. Either is works or it doesn't. If it doesn't, what's not going right? What's the error?

Comment: @Euphoric, I tried `.AsParallel() .Select() and .Where()` approach and it works fine. But, when compared to the `Parallel.ForEach` approach, In multiple times, the milliseconds is little higher. I used `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch` to test both set of codes for the execution time comparision. Finally, I am going to stick with the `Parallel.ForEach` approach, which is having less execution time in most times I tested when compared to `.AsParallel() .Select() and .Where()` approach. Thank You for your valuable suggestion and solution.

Comment: @JohnStephen You mean compared to your code? You sure you are testing correctly? If that is the case, then there is something wrong, because there is nothing in your code that would suggest it would take 10 seconds for 658 items. Other things that catch my mind is Factory.BuildLinkItem or possible lazy loading if you are using entity framework.

Comment: @Euphoric, Yes, I compared with my code and I am sure that I tested correctly. Also, If `Factory.BuildLinkItem` might be a problem in this case, whether can we have any other workaround instead of using `Factory.BuildLinkItem`. Thanks. Following is the `Factory.BuildLinkItem` definition. `public static ILinkItem BuildLinkItem(string linkName, IWorkbenchItem parent, IWorkbenchItem child)
        {         
            return new LinkItem { LinkName = linkName ?? string.Empty, Child = child, Parent = parent };
        }`

Comment: @JohnStephen Factory.BuildLinkItem is your code. You should be aware if it is doing something that might hurt performance. Maybe if you posted it, then we could figure something out. Also, are you not using Entity Framework? We need some context your code runs in.

Comment: @Euphoric, I had posted the `Factory.BuildLinkItem` code definition in the above comment section. Please see to that. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnStephen Edit your question next time. No one is going to decipher the code from comment. I still can't see how the code in the question would take 10 seconds. How long does non-parallelized, sequential code take?

Comment: @Euphoric, I had edited the question and added the `Factory.BuildLinkItem` definition. Thanks.